# Advanced Usage of Ranges with Vim Keymappings

Tags: vim, keymapping

I have a mapping in my vimrc that downwardly comments out regions of c code:

```
nmap comc :normal! I//<ESC>
```

Since the 'normal' ex command implicitly converts input such as "Ncomc" to ".,.+N-1 comc", I can range comments downwardly without many keystrokes and without leaving normal mode. This is, however, a very limited subset of what vim ranges can do. If I'm willing to be verbose, I can achieve upward ranging comments like so:

```
.,.-5 normal comc
```

While editing text, I would much prefer to type something like "-6comc" or make a mapping of "Comc" that uses upward ranges. I'm haven't been able to do so successfully.

Similarly, range operations support commenting until a search pattern is reached, e.g :

```
.,/int main/ comc
```

I would, however, like to do so without all that typing.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you requested is normally done with `:h map-operator` mapping. With this commenting 3 lines down will turn into `comc2j` though, but 3 lines up is now just as easy: `comc2k`.

You can also use visual mode without changing your mapping at all: `V2kcomc`. You will have to add `xnoremap` with the identical `lhs` and `rhs` because `nnoremap` works only for normal mode. ([And do not use `nmap`.](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html))

Third option is mapping `-` to something that moves `{count}` lines up and puts count back:

```
nnoremap <expr> - (v:count ? ":\<C-u>\n" . (v:count-1) . 'k' . v:count : '')
```

. This assumes you are writing `6-comc`, not `-6comc`.

// By the way, I would suggest `The NERD Commenter` if it comes to the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

While it's commendable to go as far as possible without any plugins, sometimes they're just the best option. What will you do when you start working in a language that has comments with `#` or `(*`...`*)`? Add new mappings for these comment characters?

I recommend [***commentary.vim***](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3695) which does filetype-aware commenting.

The default commenting operator in *commentary.vim* is `gc`. You can combine it with motions, and use it in Visual mode too.

Your use cases:

- Comment downwards N lines (say, 3): `:.,.+3normal gcc`, or `gc3j` or `4gcc`.
- Comment upwards 5 lines: `:.,.-5normal gcc`, or simply `gc5k`.
- Comment until `int main`: `:.,/int main/-1normal gcc`, or simply `gc/int main` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I do have a mapping 'comp' that comments out perl and python code and a 'comh' that comments out haskell code. I have autocommands that recursively map 'com' to whichever key-mapping I need for the filetype I'm working with. Since I've gone so far already, I would prefer to avoid switching to a plugin. That does indeed sound like a fantastic plugin, though, and I'll likely switch to it when I'm done with my 'I'M GONNA LEARN VIM' kick.